# Syntax error extra token "kMeans" after end of the expression

Tags: julia

I am using kmeans algorithms when i am using type to create a kmeans then it's giving me a error for extra token "kMeans" after end of the expression.

```
julia> type kMeans
           kMeans
       end
ERROR: syntax: extra token "kMeans" after end of expression
```

Comment: Which package are you using? See also [this notebook](https://github.com/sylvaticus/lmlj.jl/blob/master/notebooks/clusters.ipynb) for a simple implementation of kmeans and other clustering algorithms in Julia 1.x

Answer (score 1):

`type` is not a thing since Julia 1.0. You should use `mutable struct`, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Mutable-Composite-Types-1

Comment: Thank your very much